# Deprecated: Non-static method PageMainData::getOrdersHTML() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Tags: php

What is the right syntax to remove the deprecated warning?

```
public function __construct($_variables) {

    // load parent
    parent::__construct($_variables);

    // define class variables
    $_array=array(
    //  "mobileplatform"            => Mobile::isMobilePlatform(), // turn off infotip on mobiles cos it sux
        "ordertimerange"            => $this->__config->get('ordertimerange'),
        "timezone"                  => $this->__config->get('timezone'),
        "cachefolder"               => $this->__config->get('cachefolder')
    );

    // load class variables
    $this->loadClassVariables($_array);

    // load the order html
    PageMainData::getOrdersHTML();

    // load the page html
    PageMainHTML::html();

    // render page
    $this->createPage();

}
```

I tried changing  PageMainData::getOrdersHTML(); to $this->getOrdersHTML();

But then I get an Call to undefined method PageMain::getOrdersHTML() error.

Can someone provide me a solution?

Comment: You have to add more information for us to be able to help here: especially what those classes are, what library or framework you are using here.

Comment: That depends on the methods you are calling; if they don't require an object to be instantiated, make them static and don't use `$this`. If they do require an object, you should generate one before you call the method.

Comment: This is a backward compatibility issue. Many years ago in a codebase far far away the core developers thought it would be fine to call non static methods using the static syntax. This was in PHP 4 and it was changed in PHP 5 (correct me if I'm wrong). To get around this issue you either need to instantiate the class and call the method using `$pageData = new PageMainData;` then call `$pageData->getOrdersHTML()`, or change the method in the class to be static. If you change the method in the class be aware that it could break other things, for instance the `$this` will no longer work.